# Indexing oracle (XMLTYPE) attribute in elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, logstash

**Query :**

SELECT event_event_dt, event_event_tm, ilmd FROM event;

**ilmd** filed is of (XMLTYPE) in Oracle DB which contains xml document in it. I am trying to index it in elastic search using logstash.

My configuration file is below, I am not able to index it.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl"
        jdbc_user => "abc"
        jdbc_password => "abc"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/abc/ES/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        statement => "SELECT event_event_dt, event_event_tm, ilmd FROM event"
        last_run_metadata_path => "/tmp/logstash-oradb.lastrun"
        record_last_run => true
    }
}
filter {
    mutate { convert => [ "sample_time" , "string" ]}
    date { match => ["sample_time", "ISO8601"]}
    xml {
     source => "ilmd"
     xpath => ["/ilmd/@string","profile"]
   }
}
output   {
    elasticsearch {
      index => "userProfile"
      document_type => "user_data"
      workers => 2
    }
}
```

No index filed named **ilmd** has been created, neither any error on the console. Simply a message on the console "Configuration Ok".

Comment: "I am not able to index it" is a bit vague. What do you observe? Are there any errors? Provide as much info as possible, help us help you!

Comment: @Val Question modified..

Comment: Can you run logstash with the `--debug` flag and provide the output? Also remove `record_last_run` and `last_run_metadata_path` (+ delete the underlying file) from your config until we figure it out.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yu1flfxlsqvqk5/rs-debug-log.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Val Above is the link for log file, please have a look